# How to copy one var to other var in model in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie in Xamarin Forms and MVVM model as well. There is a list view in my app. Item source of the listview is through web api. I am fetching data from api and displaying in listview.

I am fetching data from api and using JSON Net to parse my data as set as datasource of ListView.

```
string uriString = "http:*****************";
var response = await httpRequest(uriString) ;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
SecondPage.bomItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BomListModel>>(response);
```

My `BomListModel` is

```
public class BomListModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int _PartNo { get; set; }
    public bool _isChecked { get; set; }
    public int _partQty { get; set; }
    public int _qty { get; set; }
    public string _partDesignation { get; set; }

    public int PartNo
    {
        get { return _PartNo; }

        set
        {
            _PartNo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PartNo"));
        }
    }
    public bool isChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }

        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("isChecked"));
        }
    }
    public int qty
    {
        get { return _qty; }

        set
        {
            _qty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("qty"));
        }
    }
    public int partQty
    {
        get { return _partQty; }

        set
        {
            _partQty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("partQty"));
        }
    }
     public string partDesignation
    {
        get { return _partDesignation; }

        set
        {
            _partDesignation = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("partDesignation"));
        }
    }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Everything is working fine. Data is displaying. 
I need to display same data in 2 pages. 
First in `BomList` as

[image]

Here user can only see the data.

I am binding data as

```
<Label Text="{Binding PartNo}" TextColor="WhiteSmoke"  FontSize="Small" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
<Label Text="{Binding partDesignation}" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  FontSize="Small" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
<Label Text="{Binding partQty}" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Small" Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Second page in `RequestQuote` I am displaying data as

[image]

Here if user selects item he can modify order qty.

Data is binded as

```
<Label Text="{Binding PartNo}" TextColor="DodgerBlue"  FontSize="Small" 
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding partDesignation}" TextColor="DodgerBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  
                                   FontSize="Small" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
<common:CustomCheckBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" 
                                        VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Checked="{Binding isChecked  ,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                        CheckedImage="checkbox_checked" UnCheckedImage="checkbox_unchecked" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
<Entry TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding partQty, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                   FontSize="Small"  VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding isChecked ,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Problem arises here. As `partQty` is binded in `TwoWay` mode, if user modifies data here my model gets updated and hence  `BomList` gets updated too. 
I have used `static` list view to share my list through out app. I have defined it in my `Second Page` as

```
public static List<BomListModel> bomItems { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to prevent data being updated?? I need `TwoWay` mode binding as I need to get quantity of product user wants to order. 
I have added one more var `qty` in my model.How can I copy `partQty` which I am getting from api to `qty`. If user modifies `qty` `partQty` should remain unaffected.

While writing this question one approach strikes through my mind. I can make duplicate copy of listview `bomItems` and use in `RequestQuote` , so that original one remains intact. Will this be good approach?? Do let me know if there any other ways to accomplish  the same.

Thanks in advance. (Apologies for posting very long question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, you could try a variant of this:

> I have added one more var qty in my model.How can I copy partQty
>   which I am getting from api to qty. If user modifies qty partQty
>   should remain unaffected.

You can copy from partQty to qty on first demand by making a change to BomListModel:

```
private int? _qty;

public int qty
{
    get
    {
        if (!_qty.HasValue)
            _qty = _partQty;
        return _qty.Value;
    }

    set
    {
        _qty = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("qty"));
    }
}
```

As long as qty is not part of the Json that gets deserialized, _qty will remain null until the value of qty is needed, at which point it is initialized with _partQty. After that, the values of qty and partQty are separate -- a change to one won't affect the other.

Your other idea:

> I can make duplicate copy of listview bomItems and use in RequestQuote , so that original one remains intact. Will this be good approach??

Could be a fine idea as well, it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  For instance, if BomListModel is meant to be fetched once from the server and then RequestQuote would use that multiple times for different quotes, this latter approach seems much better. It clearly separates the read-only data from the writable data, so you don't need to worry about data from one RequestQuote "spilling over" into the next one because qty was set in a static list and not reset in between.

BTW, it's generally considered good practice for the actual storage fields (like _qty, _partQty) to be private, not public.

Comment: Thamks @DavidS. I worked it out with your first approach. I am a newbie thanks for your advice.

Comment: Thanks. Today I implemented your first approach. It works perfectly. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Thanks for your last piece. I have changed all storage fields as private. Thankss!!